# Duplicate Id not the row id

Tags: sql-server

When I upload my table project in my SQL Server, I see appear duplicate of the row such the example below using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

```
ID      Status          Code
----------------------------------
144702  Completed       Ok-Q8 AB
144702  Completed       Ok-Q8 AB
```

I try to run the delete command but I can't make it work.. my goal it is to  scan all the table ID and see if there are a row with same ID and then delete one of them so, in the end, will be just 1 row with that ID

```
delete from project
where ID not in
(
    select min(ID)
    from project
);
```

My goal it is to  scan all the table ID and see if there are a row with same ID and then delete one of them so, in the end, will be just 1 row with that ID

Comment: tag your dbms name

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL management studio

Comment: If those are the only columns, why don't you create a new table as distinct of old table, then drop the old table and finally rename the new table as old table? It could be worthwhile to investigate why you have duplicates in the first place and institute some checks in place

Comment: @matt did you try the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        Status,
        Code,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
        ID,
        Status,
        Code,
            ORDER BY 
        ID,
        Status,
        Code,
        ) row_num
     FROM 
        project
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1;
```